# Make vhdresizer work on XP Mode VHD files

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode, vhd

I'm trying to shrink a Windows 7 XP Mode VHD file with VhdResizer with little success.

When I select my VHD file, it says "VhdExpand only supports fixed and dynamic VHD files". My XP Mode VHDs are dynamic files.

Does anyone have any idea why it is failing?

Failing that, does anyone have a process that I can use to shrink my XP mode VHD files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506047/how-to-shrink-windows-7-xp-mode-vhd-files):

Here's how I do it:

1) Make sure the VHD is shutdown (status should be Powered down)

2) In the Virtual Machines folder, click the VHD

3) Click Settings on the menu

4) Select the HD in question and click Modify

5) Select the option to Compact